# Mysql: How to filter data by using like statement in subquery

Tags: mysql, join

I've two tables as below, I wanted to filter the values where a word contains in `bad_word` table

Bad word Table

```
CREATE TABLE `bad_word` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


 id value
 1  apple
```

Item table

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

id  name
1   buy this apple
2   buy this orrange
3   buy this mango
```

I want to get final result after the filter

```
id  name
2   buy this orrange
3   buy this mango
```

Sample query I've tried

```
select * 
FROM items 
where
items.name not like CONCAT('%', select value from bad_words , '%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an anti-join approach:

```sql
SELECT i.*
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN bad_words bw
    ON i.name LIKE CONCAT('%', bw.value, '%')
WHERE bw.value IS NULL;
```

Actually, it would be better to use `REGEXP` here with word boundaries around the bad keywords:

```sql
SELECT i.*
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN bad_words bw
    ON i.name REGEXP CONCAT('\\b', bw.value, '\\b')
WHERE bw.value IS NULL;
```